# Change Color of Checkbox List Item onChange

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes + labels.  I want the background color of the list item to change when the checkbox is selected.  Currently, when the checkbox is selected, the entire list changes background color, whereas I only want the background-color of the individual item to change.  Thanks for the help!

**Code:**

```
names = ["Dave","Bob","Chuck"];
var numberOf = names.length; 
//Log the number of players and their names to the console.
console.log("You have " + numberOf + " recent players, and their names are " + names);
//Players List
var text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < numberOf; i++) {
    text += "<li class='playerListItem'><label><input type='checkbox' class='playerCheckbox'>" + names[i] + "</label></li>";
    }
text += "</ul>";
document.getElementById("recentPlayersContainer").innerHTML = text;

//Changes background of currently selected playe
$('input.playerCheckbox').on('change', function(event) {
$('li.playerListItem').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(255,102,51,0.15)');
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input.playerCheckbox').on('change', function(event) {
    $(this).closest('li.playerListItem').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(255,102,51,0.15)');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$('input.playerCheckbox').on('change', function(event) {
  $(this).closest("li").css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(255,102,51,0.15)');
});
```

It might also be worth adding that this will not remove the background colour when the checkbox is deselected. Therefore I would just use a class that you can remove and apply as appropriate.

Comment: The background color will be removed, when there is only one checkbox selected, but once multiple are selected, only the bottom-most one can be removed

Answer (score 1):

Not enough jQuery

```
$('#recentPlayersContainer').append(
    $('<ul />').append(
        $.map(["Dave","Bob","Chuck"], function(player) {
            var check = $('<input />', {
                'class' : 'playerCheckbox',
                type    : 'checkbox',
                on      : {
                    change : function() {
                        $(this).closest('li')
                        .css('backgroundColor', this.checked ? 'rgba(255,102,51,0.15)' : "");
                    }      
                }
            }),
                lbl = $('<label />', {text : player}),
                li  = $('<li />', {'class' : 'playerListItem'});

            return li.append( lbl.prepend( check ) );
        })
    )
);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qLx1nmu2/1/)

Answer (score 1):

use the 'this' keyword on the event listener.

```
$('input.playerCheckbox').on('change', function(event) {
  // 'this' below refers to the clicked element. the parents() function selects only its parent's <li>   

  $(this).parents('li').css('backgroundColor', 'rgba(255,102,51,0.15)'); 
});
```